# Connect Auth0 client app to AWS RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, single-sign-on, amazon-rds, auth0

I just started using Auth0 last week. Can anyone provide details on how you setup an Auth0  client, that connects to a custom RDS MySQL database? I"m trying to authenticate users form a Drupal Install via a login form and I consistently receive a "401" error.

Comment: Doesn't Drupal itself need to access the RDS database? User's shouldn't be accessing the database directly via Auth0. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Mark B I built a Drupal 7 multi-site architecture, where the main vendor acts as the parent site and the client installs are all in the "sites" directory.  All sites share the same user table which lives in the parent site inside an RDS database on my AWS cloud account.  My goal is to create a single sign-on then redirect for users that are members of the associated site.  You are correct Drupal does need to access the RDS and that is currently the case, but I waned to use Auth0 as the single sign-on for all of the sub-sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure both auth0 and AWS (IAM) for this, kindly go through documentation provided.

[Call AWS APIs and Resources Securely with Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws/tokens)

**Edit 1:** Do Refer to commet , will update accordingly.

Comment: Accessing the data inside an RDS instance isn't done through the AWS API, it's done through a database connection. Some database engines on RDS do support IAM authentication though, but even then you don't use the AWS API.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , I will try this in test environment and update answer .

Comment: @KushVyas Can you provide step-by-step instructions on how to set this up? I"m more of a developer then a devOps person.

Comment: if you're using a serverless RDS you'll need a bastion ec2 vm to tunnel through in order to connect to the db. I'm not sure that auth0 allows the use of such a ssh tunnel.